# How to get a Vector2 location of an object? (Unity2D javascript)

Tags: unity, 2d, javascript, ai, unityscript

I need to make an "AI" that makes a ball try to touch the player. But `Vector2.MoveTowards()`needs a Vector2 variable but how do i get the location of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vector2 is a type composed by two numbers which are x and y, then you should be able to get the position by asking both numbers:

```
 Vector2 YourVar; 
 YourVar.x; 
 YourVar.y;
```

So you should use something like:

```
 SetPositionToMove(YourVar.x,YourVar.y); //if the functions expect x and y or:
 SetPositionToMove(Point2(YourVar.x,YourVar.y)); //if it expects a Point2 for example
```

Comment: Thank you but i have changed my question becouse I've learned that you can use `Vector2.MoveTowards()`. Now i need to know how to get the position of an object in Vector2 variable. If you know the answer can you help?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean. Can you give an example code? Also i tried using a transform variable (I specified the object using it) but i don't know how to make it a vector2 variable.

Comment: I updated the answer. If I understood it fine, what you want is to get the position (the coords) of a Vector2 variable right?

Comment: One last question: how do i get the x and y coords of an object?

Comment: what type of object? what type do your object has?

Comment: Nevermind... Vector2.MoveTowards() just makes it mimic my movements for some reason...

Comment: this is how you get x,y cords :
player.transform.position.x , player.transform.position.y where player is a gameobject